# How we download pdf file in iOS?

Tags: ios, pdf, download

I want to download pdf file. Pdf file place in source code not on the server. How we download local(source) pdf file in iOS. Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean `Pdf file place in source code not on the server`? if it's local you don't need to download it...

Comment: it mean user save (download) pdf file in the device and open pdf any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Your question is vague and poorly worded. You cleared up what you meant in comments, but you should go back and edit your question.

Your question has 2 parts.

1. How do you write your app so it can download pdf files and save them locally for the user to open at some future date.
2. How do you set up your app so users can read locally stored PDF files.

For item 1, look at using `NSURLSession`. It has methods that will save a file directly to disk. You will want to save to the user's documents directory.

Item 2 is more complicated. You will have a fair amount of work to create a PDF viewer. Do a search on "Opening and Viewing a PDF" in the Xcode help system to get started.

You might also want to look at using the iOS document model to allow the user to open the PDF files as documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString *)downloadFileToCache:(NSString *)downloadURL saveWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName redownloadIfExist:(BOOL)redownload {

   //Storing to cache storage
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   if (fileName == nil)
   {
     fileName = [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:[downloadURL lastPathComponent]];
   }
   else
   {
     fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
   }

   NSString *pathDirectory = [fileName stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

   if([pathDirectory isEqualToString:@""]== NO)
   {
      if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: pathDirectory] == NO)
      {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:pathDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
      }
   }
   if (redownload == YES)
   {
      [fileManager removeItemAtPath:fileName error:nil];
   }
   if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: fileName] == NO)
   {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[downloadURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];
       [data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
   }
   return fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let _ = DownloadManager.shared.activate()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        DownloadManager.shared.onProgress = { (progress) in
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                self.progressView.progress = progress
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        DownloadManager.shared.onProgress = nil
    }

    @IBAction func startDownload(_ sender: Any) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/oversize_pdf_test_0.pdf")!
        let task = DownloadManager.shared.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer contains only code. Please, provide some useful explanations.